# Setting the value of a variable to null or to another value

Tags: c#

I am trying to set the value of sequence to null if it's null or to a value

```
 var sequence = parameters[11].Value != DBNull.Value ? 
                (int)parameters[11].Value : null;
```

But getting this message:

> Error CS0173  Type of conditional expression cannot be determined
>   because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and
>   ''

Can anyone give me advice on this one? Note that I need the (int) cast as the parameters are returned as objects.

Comment: so, what real value `parameters[11]`?

Comment: The error seems to show that the casting fails: `(int)parameters[11].Value` what is in the `parameters[11].Value`? You may consider to use `Convert.ToInt32` and `ToString()`

Comment: Have you tried editing the cast to (int?) The problem here is, the variable is going to assume it's either an int, or a null, but there's no null int, unless you make it nullable.

Comment: '' is no int so you get an error. + giving an var a null value isn´t pretty. So you could maby make a const int invalid = -1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to change the direct casting to the `Convert.ToInt32`

```
 int? sequence = parameters[11].Value != DBNull.Value ? 
    new Nullable<int>(Convert.ToInt32(parameters[11].Value.ToString())) : null;
```

Also, since you want to assign either `int` or `null`, then the data type must be `nullable` (i.e. `int?`)

Comment: Why `Convert.ToInt32(parameters[11].Value.ToString())` .. it could be simply .. `Convert.ToInt32(parameters[11].Value)`

Comment: why convert a `int` value to `string` and back to `int` at all?

Comment: @Byyo `parameters[11].Value` is likely an `object`, not an `int`. If it were an `int` the OP errors wouldn't have happened in the first place.

Comment: i agree, it's an `object` but objects can be casted / parsed. converting is the most inefficent way to go

Answer (score 4):

assuming that `var sequence` is type of `int?` you can do

```
int? sequence = parameters[11].Value != DBNull.Value ? (int?)parameters[11].Value : null;
```

Comment: Could be better if you use var, because the type is already obvious as `int?`, and declaring the variable `sequence` as `int?` is not really good practice.

Comment: @Nathan If you don't handle anonymous types or objects like `IENumberable<Usermanager.User.Student>` it's better to use the strong type. That makes the code better to read.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting your `parameters[11].Value` to `int` which does not seem to match the type of `parameters[11].Value` which you are setting.

Try to omit the `(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems: you have not declared the variable's type, and the compiler cannot work it out for itself.

```
int? sequence = (parameters[11].Value != DBNull.Value
                    ? (int)parameters[11].Value
                    : null);
```

This will compile ok, because the compiler can convert both int and null to [Nullable<int>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why nobody used **default** keyword .. it is very `important and powerful key in c#`.. you better start use of it .. in some critical generic situation .. it will play very vital role for you..

```
 var sequence = parameters[11].Value != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(parameters[11].Value) : default(int?);
```